# How to handle incoming webhook that send basic AUTH in base 64 to secure the webhook

Tags: php, curl, input, webhooks, rest

In PHP creating a webhook endpoint

```
<?php
$raw = file_get_contents('php://input');
?>
```

but the var_dupm($raw) gives me the "body parameters" How do I retrieve what is sent via header Authorization: Basic

when I do `var_dupm($_SERVER)` I don't see the header value.

So, how can I retrieve the "Basic value" ?

Comment: The username and password [should be](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php) in `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']` and `$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']`. PHP should automatically decode the base64 string into a username/password pair. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: @rickdenhaan not I get Undefined array key "PHP_AUTH_USER" same for "PHP_AUTH_PW" I have PHP 8 and latest apache